# Python Pandas: Skip reading header row but keep it and add it back when writing

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my function for reading a huge CSV file chunk by chunk and writing it back in the same manner, in chunks.

**what i want to do is:**

Skip reading the first row which is header row but keep it and add it later as headers or header row. I saw a piece of code on stack-overflow which probably extract the header but i don't know how to add it back when writing the data using to_sql

```
def csv_to_sqlite(input_file_name, output_db, output_db_table_name, size_of_chunk):
    number_of_lines = sum(1 for row in (open(input_file_name)))

    for eachRow in range(0, number_of_lines, size_of_chunk):

        df = pd.read_csv(input_file_name,
                         header=None,
                         nrows=size_of_chunk,
                         skiprows=eachRow,
                         low_memory=False,
                         error_bad_lines=False)

        # new_header = df.iloc[0]
        # df = df[1:]
        # df.columns = new_header

        df = df.drop_duplicates(keep='last')
        df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())

        df.to_sql(output_db_table_name, output_db, if_exists='append',
                  index=False,
                  chunksize=size_of_chunk)
```

Comment: What would it mean to write a csv header to sql? Can you clarify your question?

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Dropping duplicates within chunks doesn't help if there's duplicates across chunks... For instance: why not just bulk the data into the DB then DISTINCT it there?

Comment: if i knew it i would have done it, i just started learning python. would you please show me how can i do that.

Comment: Unless you're doing something more complicated than what you're showing within Python/pandas - use your DB's bulk import facility to grab the CSV data, then dedupe it there

Comment: OK, I'll have to do some research on it, the CSV file is 1 GB and i'm reading chuks of 10 rows, converting it to lower case, and removing duplication within chunk, i just realize if exact two records are in he different chukns how would i encounter that problem.

Answer (score -2):

There is no need to reinvent the wheel - use ['chunksize' parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
for df in pd.read_csv(filename, ..., chunksize=size_of_chunk):
    #process chunk here
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to address the question raised at all.

Comment: @pvg, yes, it does. If you read docs - you'll see that using `chunksize` parameter will solve that problem

Comment: @pvg this does address what the OP is trying to do (albeit the OP is reading the file once to get the line count, then N many times for however many chunks are required) - this is a far more sane and efficient solution to address that part (as there's also then no need to worry about headers as the dataframes returned will still have the same column naming)

Comment: when i add chunksize=size_of_chunk it throws an error "df = df.drop_duplicates(keep='last')
AttributeError: 'TextFileReader' object has no attribute 'drop_duplicates'" if i comment duplication like it jumps to the next line... untill the end